# In every coloring in two colors of the edges of $K_{10} $ there are at least 20 monochromatic triangles.

Tags: coloring, ramsey-theory

> In every coloring in two colors of the edges of $K_{10} $ there are at least 20 monochromatic triangles.

Can anyone give me a hint of how to approach this? I have no idea..

Comment: See also [this question](/questions/229239).

Comment: Thanks. could you please explain why the number of bi-angles in the graph is at most $m^2$ where $n=2m+1$?

Comment: The product of two numbers that adds to $2m$, $x(2m-x)$ is maximized when $x=m$.

Comment: Thank you I actually realized that a second after I asked it, and I apologize for creating a duplicate I honestly couldn't find it when I searched